# What is the cleanest way to require a global module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for my bad English, I'm new to node.js.

When I need a global module, such as `babel`. What is the cleanest way to require it in a project?

- 1. Install it in local (a little redundant if I use es6 allday).
- 2. `npm link the_module`.
- 3. `require(hard_link_of_the_module)`.
- 4. set NODE_PATH environment variable: `export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules`.
- 5. use some module, such as `requireg` to help me do this tricky.

which one is the cleanest way and why, Thank you.

Comment: If you need it in the project then it should probably be local and listed in the package.json.

Comment: There is no reason to install Babel globally, and we (the Babel devs) do not recommend it. If your module requires transpiling, it should have a devDependency on Babel.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm confused about this, when i install `babel@5.x` locally with npm, after installed it reminds me better to install it globally.

Comment: True! We've removed that warning in Babel 6 and now suggest the opposite.